# usar while o foreach para el manejo de array?

Tags: php

Me gustaría saber cuales son las ventajas y desventajas, como las situaciones para usar el while y el foreach trabajandose con arreglos

He trabajado con ambos pero no se en que se diferencian, si he notado es que el while cuando obtiene los valores si usas dentro de este dos hechos, el primer echó carga la variable 0 y el segundo la variable 1, es decir como si fuera usándolos en cada accion

Comment: Ya leí todo el post, la cosa no es el for normal, sino foreach ya que este esta hecho específicamente para arrays, y pues usarlo solo porque se que cantidad trabajaré no me funciona pues tendría que obtener la cantdad de los registros

Comment: Jejeje tranquilo, además el foreach no tiene cantidad jajaja o que yo halla visto

Comment: por fin te respondi, espero que se entienda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for y while**

cuando se usa un `for(int i=0; i<contenedor.length; i++)` la iteracion se basa en el valor de una variable adicional, en este caso `i` por lo tanto es completamente dependiente de `i` las tareas que se realizaran dentro del `for`, es decir que para acceder a la coleccion y manipularlo, dependera del valor de `i`, lo mismo sucede con `while`, ademas que `i` puede referenciar a elementos **inexistentes** por eso el **error `IndexOut`**

**por que usar foreach?**

En este caso no es dependiente de ninguna variable adicional al contexto de la logica del problema, sino en realidad trabaja directamente con elementos **existentes** de la coleccion.

Comment: Entonces mejor el foreach porque no depende de otro valor.

Comment: Tambien se evitaria usar el MySQL array o como se implementaría?